# jira and git linking up

Tags: git, jira

I recently moved to jira for my bug management tool. I have installed the most recent copy which 4.1. We use Git as our version control system, I am looking to set it up, so looking around i found that the [Git Integration Plugin for JIRA](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/4984) by BigBrassBand is one of the most popular.

Unfortunately, like all things that happen in my day, its only fully compatible with Jira 3.13.

Anyone have suggestions for managing this, or working around it.

Also anything pre/post commit hooks with jira/git would be helpful too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see in [this changeset](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/source/changelog/JGIT?cs=152826), regarding the [Jira Git Plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JGIT/JIRA+Git+Plugin) you mentioned:

- JGit 0.5 will be out soon, with a Jira 4 compatibility built-in.
- For right now, you can try that [GitHub repo](http://github.com/isungurov/jira4-git-plugin),  with Jira 4 support and branch 
  support

Note (2011), as [CharlesB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11343/charlesb) mentions in the comments, the latest JGit versions have all Jira4 compatibility:

#### 0.6 Release Notes (27/Mar/2011)

> - migrated to v2 plugin system
> - **Jira 4.3** support
> - web links for Gitorius and cgit

#### 0.5.3 Release Notes (13/Feb/2011)

> - Jira 4.2 fixes
> - [...]

[...]

#### 0.5.1 Release Notes (15/Nov/2010)

> - support for Jira 4.1
> - tracking multiple branches

Comment: Thanks.

Have you managed to set it up? Repository Root and Repository Origin??

Comment: @garbagecollector: no, I haven't tested it yet. At least, the support for Jira4 is in progress.

Comment: new version 0.6 now supports Jira 4

Comment: @CharlesB: good point. I have illustrated it in my revised answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use JIRA -> FishEye -> Git

Admittedly, FishEye is another expense, but that might be preferable to messing around with plugins that only half work. FishEye also gives you a lot more information about your repositories.

Be aware that at present, the FishEye index (that is created from your Git repository) will take around 3x the space of the Git repository.  Atlassian is looking into this and making some improvements in the area.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a self-hosted [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/gitorious) for git repository management, and [klonfisch](http://github.com/netresearch/klonfisch) as bridge between Gitorious and JIRA (using the JIRA FishEye plugin).

Answer (score 1):

For those wanting to integrate Git and Jira at the present time, one can use

- [Git Integration for Jira by BigBrassBand (a GitKraken company)](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/4984/git-integration-for-jira)

If one is using GitHub, one can use both the previous or the following

- [GitHub for Jira by Atlassian](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219592/github-for-jira) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/atlassian/github-for-jira)) - [Introduced back in 2018](https://github.blog/2018-10-04-announcing-the-new-github-and-jira-software-cloud-integration/)

For additional information on this one, [read here](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/integrate-with-github/).

If one is using GitLab, [read here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jira/index.html).

If one is using BitBucket, [read here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/jira-integration-776639874.html).

Picking one would be a matter of one's requirements (if using GitHub then GitHub's plan/edition - Free, Team, Enterprise -, Jira's hosting type - Cloud, Server, Data Center - and more).

For additional information on how to integrate Jira with development tools, [read here](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/integrate-with-development-tools/).